# How can I find out if my HD is SATA II?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

In the [specifications](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/search/1/a_id/5391#) (my HD is WD3200BEVT) it says SATA 3GB/s.

Does it mean that my HD is SATA II?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the transfer speed of SATA II is 3Gb/s. SATA I is 1.5Gb/s and SATA III is 6Gb/s. They are all interchangeable but you will only reach the transfer speeds that your slowest component supports (motherboard or drive).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 3Gb/s SATA equal SATA 2

---

Longer answer with some background:

Currently there are three SATA standards:

```
 SATA 1, aka SATA 1.5GB/sec
 SATA 2, aka SATA 3.0GB/sec
 SATA 3, aka SATA 6.0GB/sec
```

In theory all devices are compatible. A SATA-2 drive on a SATA-1 controller should just work, albeit at a maximum transfer speed of about 130MB/sec. ( SATA-1 speed, and compensating for the overhead in the protocol and the encoding).

A single harddisk is not that fast and SATA-1 is still more than adequate for regular desktop usage.

Most SSDs are a lot faster and will be limited by SATA-1, for those you really want SATA-2 or 3.  Another use for faster SATA speeds is with port multipliers and several harddisks on a single SATA link.

But, for normal desktop use: Everything **should** be interchangeable. A few are not and most of those have jumpers to fall back to SATA-1. (Essentially this means the firmware on the HDD is not up to snuff. It should not be needed).

Comment: Thanks for the "extra" info. :)
Even though you said SATA I is still mora adequate for regular desktop usage, I will go with exchanging the HD for a sata II HD to avoid any problems. tks!

Comment: No reason not to buy SATA-2 or -3. (Find a -1 in the shops might even be hard. And the last HDD I bought was -3 because it was faster and cheaper then then previous -2 model).

Answer (score 0):

[Sandra lite](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk//redirect/dload.php?id=136) will tell you. Run the program and under Mainboard, there is disc controller.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Speccy will give you all the info on your system specs, including the temperatures of all the primary components.

[Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy)

Comment: As several other answers indicate, third party software isn't needed to answer the question.

Comment: No doubt, Speccy just answers the question and adds many other cool and useful specs.

Comment: This was actually suggested 2 yrs ago in a similar answer and that got deleted.  However, another answer suggests Sandra lite, so go figure.